# How to aligning comments in R

Tags: r, vertical-alignment

I have a question: Is there any way (function, keyboard shortcut, addin or something like that) that allows me to align the comments next to the code in R in a practical way?
I mean, how can I align the comments as shown below without having to press a space or tab key so many times?

```
library(tidyverse)      # For tidyverse universe
library(rio)            # Swiss army knife of data importing
library(pacman)         # For installing and loading multiple packages at once
library(rstatix)        # For hypothesis testing
library(doBy)           # For collapsing data as in Stata
```

That alignment of the comments was achieved by pressing the space key multiple times, but the idea is to do it in a more intelligent way. I have explored the [Styler](https://github.com/r-lib/styler) addin but it doesn't do it exactly like that, since it modifies all the selected code, not only the comments.
Any suggestions?

Comment: A semi-efficient manual approach involves using multiple-cursors (in RStudio via Ctrl+Alt+arrow or something similar in another IDE), hit alt-rightarrow to move them all to the end of their respective lines, place the # symbol, and then tab them over a couple of times.  The tabbing helps with alignment.  Not the solution you're after, but fairly quick if you only have 5 lines.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion, I think it will be very useful when I have few lines. Greetings!

Comment: R scripts are just text files and IDEs are text editors at heart. Your question doesn't appear to be about R but about editing code (i.e., text). You should fix the tags.

Comment: {styler} [supports alignment](https://styler.r-lib.org/articles/detect-alignment.html), but currently not the type that you are asking for.